# Does a company go bankrupt if its cash balance goes negative?

Tags: cash

I can understand that company could be doing fine with negative cash flow, but what if the "Cash and cash equivalents at the end of period" becomes negative or reaches 0?

Comment: FWIW in theoretical models (Merton Model, etc.), the firm goes bankrupt when the market value of equity goes to zero (not when the cash goes to zero).

Answer (score 3):

When a company runs out of cash and cash equivolents, then it goes to look for financing for the cash shortfall.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treasury_management is what most large companies do to manage there cash. Now if a company borrows money and cannot pay it back and cannot refinacne the debt then it is real trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Bankruptcy, Chapter 11, Liquidation, etc. are all legal statuses of a company. I.e. registered forms have been filled out and submitted to the authorities and the company is then afforded some legal protections with respect to its debt obligations.

Having a cash balance of zero is simply an operational status of a company.

The two are not at all equivalent:

A company can be bankrupt with a positive cash balance but many more debt obligations outstanding.

A company can have zero cash balance without being in a bankrupt status, for example if it just spent all all its cash on a project which is expected to yield high returns.

A negative cash balance might be interpreted as a cash balance of zero and the company having been extended an overdraft (short term loan)